# Android: How to use selector for background of a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-button

I would like my TextView to paint with a different color background when pressed. The below xml contains a Button and TextView, both of which specify a Selector as their background.  The Button works as expected, but the TextView does not change color when pressed.  Is there a way to make this work for the TextView?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView 
        android:text="temporary text view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:background="@drawable/blackselector"
        />    
    <Button
        android:text="temporary button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:background="@drawable/blackselector"
        />   
</LinearLayout>
```

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="#FF0000" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="#00FF00" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set this to your TextView:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: Interesting how my answer was posted earlier, but did not get accepted. Hmm.

Comment: @PaulBurke Yes, I'm also wondering. But in my defense, I did not see that there was an other answer at the time I posted mine. I'm guessing ab11 did'nt notice which answer was posted earlier. But I did upvote yours.

Comment: No worries. Obviously not your fault (I actually intended to comment on the question). Thanks for the upvote! :-)

Answer (score 9):

Add

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 4):

the above about setting clickable to true is correct. Additionally, if you add a onClickListener Android sets clickable to true for you automatically.

```
// From the View class.
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    if (!isClickable()) {
        setClickable(true);
    }
    getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is outdated. Adding `android:clickable="true"` to `TextView` XML will not work now. Instead, add the following attribute to the `TextView` XML code.

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```